# JSONLD: how to define a "miscellaneous" property with unpredictable sub properties?

Tags: json-ld

I'm working on a context extension of Verifiable Credentials and one of the properties in it will act as a `metadata` holder, with properties that can vary from one Credential document to another, and that are user set and hence relatively unpredictable (at least at `@context` level).

I was curious to find a way to define such a property in JSONLD?
The structure would be something like:

```
 metadata: {
   unknown1: '...',
   unknown2: '...',
   ...
 }
```

But my validator identifies `unknown1` and `unknown2` as unmapped properties, and that bothers me.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the route that was taken down was to stringify the value of property. Since it's now just a json string, there is no issue with expectability.